# Custom formatting for `util.inspect()`

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, formatting

I'm searching for a way to format the output from [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options) cleanly (possible without regex replacing).

Currently this code:

```js
const obj = {
    x: {
        y: "",
    },
    foo: {
        bar: "abc",
        baz: true,
    },
    stuff: {
        a: "",
        b: "",
        c: "",
    },
};

console.log(
    util.inspect(obj)
);
```

Results in:

```
{
  x: { y: '' },
  foo: { bar: 'abc', baz: true },
  stuff: { a: '', b: '', c: '' }
}
```

Is there a clean way to preserve (or at least partially recreate) the original formatting? Unfortunately `util.inspect()` does not provide options to e.g. change the indentation, quotes (single/double) <strike>or linebreaks</strike> *(it does, see edit)* after every property. 
<sub>(I [opened an issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47744) as well in case other people would want that feature as well)</sub>

I can't use `JSON.stringify()` because I want to preserve JS properties as well, and I also do not want the properties to be quoted. Reading the entire file as string and somehow extracting the desired object isn't really a good solution either.

Is there a clean workaround for that? If possible, a nodejs built-in utility and no third party code formatting module.

Edit: Apparently `util.inspect()` provides the `compact` option which solves the linebreaks when set to false.

Comment: "*Is there a clean way to preserve (or at least partially recreate) the original formatting?*" there is no "original formatting". An object literal only defines an object, not its representation. You could the format the output in various ways, for example adding a new line at the start of each object or not. But you cannot determine what the original format was.

Comment: Yes, I'm ware that the formatting isn't part of the object. That's why I included "partially recreate" in the question. Though one of the formatting issues apparently is provided by util.inspect: `compact: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using `util.inspect()` at all because it breaks on some deeply nested objects. Which is why I now made a custom function that preserves non-JSON attributes on the Object:

```js
const stringifyObject = function(obj, indent = 0){
    const indentStr = " ".repeat(indent);
    const entries = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
        if (typeof value === "function")
            return `${indentStr}    ${key}: ${value.toString()},`;
        else if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null)
            return `${indentStr}    ${key}: ${stringifyObject(value, indent + 4)},`;
        return `${indentStr}    ${key}: ${JSON.stringify(value)},`;
    }).join("\n");
    return `{\n${entries}\n${indentStr}}`;
};
```

It ain't pretty, but it works.

```js
const stringifyObject = function(obj, indent = 0){
    const indentStr = " ".repeat(indent);
    const entries = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
        if (typeof value === "function")
            return `${indentStr}    ${key}: ${value.toString()},`;
        else if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null)
            return `${indentStr}    ${key}: ${stringifyObject(value, indent + 4)},`;
        return `${indentStr}    ${key}: ${JSON.stringify(value)},`;
    }).join("\n");
    return `{\n${entries}\n${indentStr}}`;
};

const obj = {
    foo: {
        bar: 1,
        baz: true,
    },
    stuff: {
        a: "foo",
        c: () => "abc",
        d: function(x){
            const a = 1 + x;
            return ++a;
        },
    },
};

console.log("const obj = " + stringifyObject(obj));
```

The only *problem* with the current approach is that template literals are instantly evaluated:

```js
{ a: `x`, }         -> { a: "x", }
{ a: `x: ${1+1}`, } -> { a: "x: 2", }
```